# Coins not adding when += is called

Tags: python

I'm still working on the game I talked about in previous question, and I'm trying to add coins when the player kills an enemy, code:

```
    elif monster_life <= 0:
      print(green + "\nYou killed a monster!")
      coins = int(coins)
      coins += 7
      monsters_killed += 1
      break
```

but I cannot get it to add the coins, there's no error message or anything just this failing. The full code can be seen here: https://replit.com/@y33t3rs0n/AddToMonsterFight

Edit: with the help of my brother and your answers I was able to get this working, sorry if I sound (or are) like a skid.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], one that depends not upon external links.

Comment: The variable `coins` inside of the function scope is different from the global `coins` variable.  You should either `return` the value from the function, or wrap this state up into a `class`.  (You can also declare the local `coins` as `global`, but I don't recommend that.)

Comment: Short answer: `coins` is a local variable (due to being received as an argument), which you neither return nor assign to anything visible outside the function scope. It has nothing to do with the global of the same name.

Comment: You are passing the *value of* the global `coins` variable to this function, as a parameter named `coins`.  There is no further connection between the two names - assigning a value to the local variable does not affect the global variable.  The simplest solution would be to use it as a global variable always - put a `global coins` statement inside the function, rather than receiving the value as a parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a close look into your code and as others pointed out in the above comments, the problem is that you are passing the global variable `coins` to the `attack` function here:

```py
attack(lives, weapon_damage, coins,    monsters_killed, bright_yellow, bright_blue, green,  bright_red)
```

Because integer values are immutable (not modifiable), the argument is passed by value, and not by reference. What this means is that inside your `attack` function, you have a different `coins` variable which is equal to the global `coins` variable. Modifying it inside the function by adding 7 coins won't change the global value.

If you want to dig deeper into what "pass by value" and "pass by reference" means, you should check this article: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pass-by-reference-vs-value-in-python/

Cheers!

Comment: As the article you linked to says, Python doesn't really distinguish between pass by reference and pass by value. All arguments are handled the same. The difference happens when you use `+=`, which behaves differently for mutable types than for immutable ones.

Comment: Instead of the link you gave, I'd recommend [this blog post by Ned Batchelder](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) to really understand how Python variables work.